# Access DateTime enumerations: Property is not static

Tags: f#

I have a sequence of DateTime objects, and I would like to get just the Sundays. .net has the `DateTime` struct, [with a DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_DayOfWeek) property. Now, consider the following bit of code:

```ml
let sundaysFirstOfMonth = dateRange |> Seq.filter (fun d -> d.DayOfWeek = DateTime.DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

This does not compile with a `Property 'DayOfWeek' is not static`, while this

```ml
let sundaysFirstOfMonth = dateRange |> Seq.filter (fun d -> int d.DayOfWeek = 0)
```

does, as I know that Sunday maps to 0 in the enumeration.

How can I make use of the enumerations without having to cast to int and reference to the int itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. This works:

```ml
let sundaysFirstOfMonth = dateRange |> Seq.filter (fun d -> d.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

I misunderstood where the enumerations was defined. It is indeed in the `System` namespace, not in `System.DateTime`